# Removing form_start from twig views Symfony3.4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

In order to customize the views of the new user page, I need to remove the elements `{{ form_start(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}` from my twig template new.html.twig.  It lets the page unorganized. Unfortunately, when I delete it, the insert new user don't display.
here is my twig code new.html.twig :

```html
<div class="content">

{{ form_start(form) }}

    <form class="form-horizontal group-border-dashed" action="#" style="border-radius: 0px;">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                Username
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Username'}} ) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                EMAIL
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'EMAIL '}} ) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <--! and so on -->

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />

        {{ form_end(form) }}

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('users_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </form>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove the `form_start` and `form_end` from my twig

Comment: Did you try to `theme` your form instead of remove `form_start` : Like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) ?

Answer (score 0):

have you consider using the options of `form_start`?

like this :

```
form_start(form, 'attr':{ 'class':'form-horizontal group-border-dashed', 'style': 'border-radius: 0px;'})
```

you'll be able to remove the `<form>` but keep a concitent templating

> note that the style should'nt be in your html page but in your css file. If you're using bootstrap you have access to [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/borders/#border-radius) :

```
<span class="rounded-0"></span>
```

> PS : if you fully template your form, you won't have access to the individual errors of each form that are autogenerated by symfony. read [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-functions) for more info.

### post edit

I have edited your question to see it more clearly and new questions arised.
why are you using the `form_widget(form)` if you create all the element by yourself ? 
you forgot the `form_rest(form)`that create the hidden csrf token (essential for security) and finnaly if you want to keep your `<ul>` inside the form why closing the form with `form_end(form)` before ?